# how to make webpage load from specific point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website in which i have added a image at the top.i want my web page to start from just below the image 
 [view image for clarifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j5rc.png)
hope you understand what I am trying to describe, if not please do ask me for clarifications.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then place the rest of your page below the image? I don't see the problem.

Comment: If you're adding an image to the website, this is part of the webpage, so I don't see how the webpage will 'start' after the image. It sounds like you want an image at the top and the rest of your website below the image. Nothing crazy about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With plain JS you could do it by using [`window.scrollTo(x, y);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) where `x` and `y` are integers representing pixels.

For example:

`window.scrollTo(0, 200);` will scroll your window down `200px` upon pageload.

You could also go for an alternative solution using a *named anchor* and a *hashtag url*

When you enter this url: (change everything before the `#` to match your url ofcourse.) `http://yourdomain.com/#mynamedanchor`

And in your markup you have

```
<img src="..." height="200" />
<a name="mynamedanchor"></a>
```

The window will automatically start at that point but this requires that you send a link with the `#mynamedanchor` within it which is not nice.

A solution for that would be to *redirect* your users who land on the page without the `#mynamedanchor` part in the url and direct them to the same page that has it using server technology like PHP but this is quite a bad idea to say the least so I would stick with the `window.scrollTo(x, y);` solution - it is by far most clean and it degrades gracefully if JS is disabled (the scroll simply won't happen which isn't the end of the world)

Comment: thankx. this one worked for me :) :)

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) solution:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop(200); // set position in pixels (height of image)
});
```

Comment: Please don't introduce libraries that aren't mentioned or tagged. You don't need 10,000 lines of JS code to get the scrollTop.

Comment: But one can get idea that scrolling up to image height can do the work easy

Comment: This downvoting is like new SO fashion or what. Just pointed out another solution, didn't I.